# How to create instance of an entity class and create EF repository with it in c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

How can i create instance of an EFEntity and create repository by using it and call 'Delete' method of the repository and delete the entity object.

`Type type = BuildManager.GetType("VPS.EntityFramework.Entites." + EntityName + ",VPS.EntityFramework", false, true);
var entity = Activator.CreateInstance(type);`

I tried the code above and get the entity.But i couldn't use it for creating repository and call "Delete" method of the repository.

(something like

`var repository = UnitofWork.CreateRepositry<entity>();
 repository.Delete(entity);
 UnitOfWork.SaveChanges();` )

Is there any suggestions about it?

Comment: This doesn't really make much sense to me. Why do you create an entity instance using reflection? What do you expect to be deleted from the Database when you call `Delete()`? The entity instance is not coming from the Database, so there is nothing to delete for EF. Have you considered to simply query the entity you want to delete from the context / repository, and then delete that entity?

Comment: I have a base form in my project that including Save,Edit and Delete buttons. All the other forms will be inherited from that base form. So I don't want to do delete operation for each forms.I want to do it in base form once. I handle the entity name in base form and i want to create an entity instance by using the name and delete it.